# Why the name of the app is the same as the name of the main activity label even that the **intent-filter** has an label attribute

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

The name of the app that appear in the home screen is the same as the name of the main activity label, I added a label attribute to the **intent-filter** but nothing is changing.

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".RingtonesActivity"
        android:label="@string/ringtones_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".PhoneState.PhoneStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

the name of the app is still **`@string/ringtones_activity_label`**.

what is wrong?

Comment: Try clean and Rebuild Project and than run it

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Can you post your activity code ?

Comment: it's 250 line and Stack OverFlow don't allow you to post a question with a lot of code and few words "Details".

Comment: Just wanna check weather you are setting any title programatically...Anyways check my answer it might work

Comment: I think you misunderstood me?

Comment: the problem is that I want to set a title for the activity, but when i write anything in the **label** attribute of the activity, this add a title to the activity, but it also change the name of the application that appear in the home screen of the phone.

Comment: Yeah i misunderstood....Have you tried uninstalling the app and run again from the code ?

Comment: yes, I tried to re-install the app

Comment: Just keep the app name in label and if you want to set title to an activity you can programtically do that by `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");`

Comment: it's working, thank you for the idea.

Comment: Did uninstalling worked ??

Comment: No? I mean the idea to set the title in from java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the app name in label and if you want to set title to an activity you can programtically do that by

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the value of label in activity tag

```
<activity
    android:label="Your title, displayed on the home screen"
```